# Loading parameter from store is undefined

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have a screen with jobs that I fetch from an API. In my screen, I want to show a message until the jobs are fetched, then display them on the screen. I am triggering the jobs fetch in componentDidMount(), then trying to display them in RenderJobs(). The problem is that props.isLoading is undefined for whatever reason.

I am using hardcoded values for the API call at the moment. Once I get the data to display properly, I'll change this.

Here is my JobsComponent:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchJobs} from '../redux/ActionCreators';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        jobs: state.jobs
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchJobs: (address, jobTitle) => dispatch(fetchJobs(address,     jobTitle))
});

function RenderJobs(props) {
    console.log('In RenderJobs, props is: ' + props.jobsData + ' / '     + props.isLoading);

const renderJobItem = ({item, index}) => {
    return (
        //UI view to show data
    );
}

if (props.isLoading) {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 30, color: colors.white}}>The     data is loading...</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
else if (props.errMess) {
    return(
        <View>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 30, color: colors.white}}>{props.errMess} </Text>
        </View>
    );
}
else {
    return (
        //UI view to show data
    );
}

}

class Jobs extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchJobs([26.1410638, 44.4346588], "Developer");
    }
render() {
        return(
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.bkg}>

                <RenderJobs 
                    jobsData={this.props.jobs}
                    isLoading={this.props.jobs.isLoading}
                    errMess={this.props.jobs.errMess} 
                    />
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}
```

This is my reducer:

```
import * as ActionTypes from '../ActionTypes';

export const jobs = (state = {   isLoading: true,
                             errMess: null,
                             jobs:[]}, action) => {

switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.GET_JOBS:
        return {...state, isLoading: false, errMess: null, jobs:     action.payload};

    case ActionTypes.JOBS_LOADING:
        return {...state, isLoading: true, errMess: null, jobs: []}

    case ActionTypes.JOBS_FAILED:
        return {...state, isLoading: false, errMess: action.payload};

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And this is the action creator:

```
export const fetchJobs = (address, job) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(jobsLoading());
  var obj = {"origin": [26.1410638, 44.4346588], "job_details": ["Developer"]};
  //fetch the data
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(jobs => dispatch(addJobs(jobs)))
    .catch(error => dispatch(jobsFailed(error.message)));
};


export const addJobs = (jobs) => ({
  type: ActionTypes.GET_JOBS,
  payload: jobs
});

export const jobsLoading = () => ({
  type: ActionTypes.JOBS_LOADING
});

export const jobsFailed = (errmess) => ({
  type: ActionTypes.JOBS_FAILED,
  payload: errmess
    });
```

I am expecting for 2 things to happen.

1. In the RenderJobs() function, I am counting on props.isLoading to give me the loading state. However, it is undefined. I can see in the logs that the JOBS_LOADING action is dispatched, and that the jobs data is correctly fetched.
2. Once the jobs data is fetched, I expect it to be displayed in the UI. However, this is not the case - I just see a blank screen.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you define value of `isLoading` flag as false from default props. This way `isLoading` will be false in first render and then could be updated by dispatching action,

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you mean by "default props". Could you give a code example, please? Also, the loading action is dispatched in the action creator in the fetchJobs() function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have forgotten to add `isLoading` in your `mapStateToProps`.

Answer (score 0):

`isLoading` will be undefined on first render as you have not defined any default value. You could provide default value using default props.

```
Jobs.defaultProps = {
  jobs: {
    isLoading: false
  }
}
```

Comment: This works fine, in the sense that if I set isLoading:true in the default props, the screen shows the loading message that I want. The problem is that, after the jobs are fetched from the API, they are not displayed in the UI (the UI gets stuck with the loading message). Any ideas why?

Comment: I am not sure where you are calling connect method. You need to debug and add break-point in `mapStateToProps`, when API call is complete and fetch complete, reducer updates store, because of connect method `Jobs` component will be re-rendered --> `mapStateToProps`  will be called again with updated props (jobs.isLoading as false)

Comment: The connect method is called at the end of my .js file - export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Jobs);

I'll try to add the breakpoints you mentioned and let you know of the result.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was. In my configureStore.js, I had forgotten to add the jobs reducer to the store. Thanks to everyone for your answers!

```
import {jobTitles} from './reducers/jobTitles';
import {jobs} from './reducers/jobs';
import {persistStore, persistCombineReducers} from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/es/storage';

export const ConfigureStore = () => {
    const config = {
        key: 'root',
        storage,
        debug: true
    };

    const store = createStore(
        persistCombineReducers(config, {
            jobTitles,
            jobs //I added this line and it fixed the problem!
        }),
        applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
    );
    const persistor = persistStore(store);


    return {persistor, store};
}
```